# R FactoMineR: Return cluster membership

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have produced an `HCPC` object and would like to return a list of the observations and which clusters they have fallen into.  I can't find a command to do this; does anyone know?

FYI, here is my work:

```
file <- read.csv("file", header=TRUE) 
library(FactoMineR) 
res.mca = MCA(file, graph=FALSE) 
# manually cut tree according to inertia gain 
res.hcpc = HCPC(res.mca, nb.clust=0)
```

---

**Edit:** A reproducible example:

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(tea)
res.mca  <- MCA(tea, quanti.sup = 19, quali.sup = 20:36)
res.hcpc <- HCPC(res.mca, nb.clust = 5)
```

Comment: It'd be nice to have `"file"` to work with (even more would be a small example showing the result you expect).

Comment: Sure, thanks.  This example should work - I'm mainly just trying to return the cluster membership detail from any given HCPC object:

Comment: library(FactoMineR)
data(tea)
res.mca=MCA(tea,quanti.sup=19,quali.sup=20:36)
res.hcpc=HCPC(res.mca, nb.clust=5)

Comment: Sorry, meant to format those lines before hitting 'enter'.

Comment: You should be able to edit your post and your comments. I've edited the post for you.

Answer (score 4):

The output `$data.clust` gives the a dataframe with the input data and a column (the last one) with the cluster the individuals belong.

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(tea)
res.mca  <- MCA(tea, quanti.sup = 19, quali.sup = 20:36)
res.hcpc <- HCPC(res.mca, nb.clust = 5)
res.hcpc$data.clust
```

Note that if you want that the individuals are in the same order as in the input dataset, you should use the argument `order=FALSE` in HCPC :

```
res.hcpc <- HCPC(res.mca, nb.clust = 5, order=FALSE)
res.hcpc$data.clust
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this post was written 3 years ago, my answer can be of help for readers. I was just looking for a solution to the same question as I used HCPC for outliers detection and here is the idea I got: I extracted a subset from the dataframe $data.clust issued from hcpc(), based on the field "cluster". 
**outliers<-subset(DHCPC$data.clust, clust==4)**

I found the answer here: [how to extract a subset of a data frame based on a condition involving a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field)