# Summarize variable by frequency for all non blank values using ddplyr

Tags: r

I  have a dataframe that looks like:

```
 example<- data.frame(interact= c("A_X", "", "", "D_W", "E_Q", "A_X"), 
                      region= seq(1,6, 1), loc= seq(20, 25, 1))
```

I would like to summarize the freqency of the `interact` column but only for those with entries. My current method is returning counts of blank rows.

Here is the output for the example I would like:

```
output<- data.frame(interact= c("A_X","D_W", "E_Q"), 
                      freq= c(2, 1,1))
```

Here is the code I have tried, but it returns the sum of the blank rows as well:

```
output<-example %>%
   group_by(interact) %>%
   summarise(freq = n())
```

Comment: Can't you simply filter out the the blank rows ? `example %>% filter(interact != "") %>% count(interact)`

Comment: That works! How simple...Do you have a suggestion regarding how to incorporate arguments that name the count column `freq` rather than `n`?

Comment: `... %>% rename(freq = n)`

Comment: Tempted to close as duplicate of [how to subset data based on field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445619/903061)

Comment: Thank you, however I get the following error: `Error in rename(., freq = n) : unused argument (freq = n)`

Comment: Really? Works fine for me on your sample data. Are you sure you didn't load `plyr` after `dplyr` and ignore the warning about function masking? Try `... %>% dplyr::rename(freq = n)` to make sure you are using the `dplyr` version.

Comment: I didn't have plyr loaded, however your solution still work. Maybe tidyverse loads plyr ? I had that one opened. Thank you

Comment: Other packages probably also have `rename` functions. `tidyrverse` doesn't load `plyr`, but some other packages might. You can use `sessionInfo` to see what packages are attached, and `?rename` may give you options of which `rename` you want to see the help for.

Comment: Thank you for  explaining that to me...I am learning more and more about R, stackoverflow has been a great resource because people like you explain how the R language works, without it is like getting a poor exam grade and not understanding why or how you can improve. I guess for many of us, this equates stackoverflow to office hours.