# How to bind and sort multiple columns into a treemap in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-visualization, treemap, data-cleaning

This is my first StackOverflow post. I think my main problem here is not having the vocabulary to ask this question, but I'll try my best below.

I have data with the following structure.

```
 Neighborhood Dominant.Discipline Rent.vs.Own ADA.Compliant
         Alki            Heritage           O             Y
      Ballard           Multi-use  Don't.know       Partial
      Ballard     CommunityCenter           R       Partial
     Belltown               Music           O             N
```

As you can see, I have more than one instance of a neighborhood, more than one instance of the `Dominant.Discipline`, of `Rent.vs.Own` and `ADA.Complianct`.

What I want to do is create a visualizations by taking a particular neighborhood, only pick the spaces that are rented and have some `ADA.compliant` status.

I then want to compare other neighborhoods on the same parameters on a Treemap. How do I achieve this?

My ideal treemap will display various neighborhoods, the surface area will represent the number of rented spaces, and the colors will represent the ADA compliance status. Red being "N", Blue being "Y", and yellow being "I don't know."

Please excuse me if I may be unclear. I'm just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Denis. The first link doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You can have a look here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemapify/treemapify.pdf , and here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field