# Not getting row count, unless providing decimal expression in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Why `nrow`/`NROW`  is not giving results without decimal expression in R?

I tried calculating the number of rows in R and did not get results with `nrow`/`NROW`.

I tried the `summary` option but with that, I have to provide decimal expression.

I rounded the column using `df$WAGE_RATE <- round(df$WAGE_RATE, digit = 0)`

```r
> class(h1b$WAGE_RATE)
"numeric"


> nrow(df$WAGE_RATE < '1000000')
NULL


> nrow(df$WAGE_RATE < '1000000.00')
NULL


> summarise(df, ct = sum(as.numeric(WAGE_RATE < '100000')))
 A tibble: 1 x 1
     ct
  <dbl>
1     0


> summarise(df, ct = sum(as.numeric(WAGE_RATE < '100000.00')))
 A tibble: 1 x 1
     ct
  <dbl>
1  9052
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are dealing with a `numeric` column, you should not compare to a character (i.e. `'1000000'`).

Second, When you do a comparison, you'll get a vector with `TRUE/FALSE`. Look at the example below:

```r
mtcars$mpg < 22
 # [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 # [12] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  
 # [23] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As `TRUE` is equivalent of `1`, you can get the `sum` and it tells you number of rows which are satisfying that condition (If you count number of `TRUE` entries, you'll see `23` of them).

```r
sum(mtcars$mpg < 22)
 # [1] 23
```

But if you want to use `nrow`, you need to provide it with a data.frame. For that, you need to subset your data based on that condition. You can read more about that here: [Extract a subset of a dataframe based on a condition involving a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/extract-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field). I simply provide the solution:

```r
nrow(mtcars[mtcars$mpg < 22,])
 # [1] 23
```