# Creating a data frame with a subset from another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame of penguin information one column is species. There are 3 species in total. I want to create a data frame for each species with all their related information. I tried subsetting but the data frame that outputs has all the same species as the original. here's my code:

adelie <- subset(penguins_clean, species = "Adelie Penguin (Pygoscelis adeliae)")

og data frame: penguins_clean

column: species

species I want to have its own data frame: Adelie Penguin (Pygoscelis adeliae)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract a subset of a dataframe based on a condition involving a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/extract-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field)

Comment: I found the issue! I needed to type:   species ==